# How to visualise a range of values logarithmically?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logarithm

I am visualising bubbles for cities, bigger if the city has a bigger value. Eg:

```
London: 14500
New York: 100
Tokyo: 1100
```

The values range from ~100-15000

I am having trouble creating a function that will return reasonable values, so that the 100 value bubbles aren't too small. The only way I could think to do this is to set a minimum size, eg:

```
if (size < 5) { size = 5 }
```

However, this causes the cities with values of ~100 to look very similar to cities with values of ~1000. I'd like the values of approx 0-15000 to return as values between 0.5 and 1 (or something similar). How would this be done?

Here's what I have so far, but like I said it's causing values of 100 and values of 1000 to both be under the min value:

```
var minBulletSize = 7.5;
var maxBulletSize = 20;
var maxSquare = maxBulletSize * maxBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;
var minSquare = minBulletSize * minBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;

// create circle for each location
for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
    var dataItem = mapData[i];
    var value = dataItem.value;
    // calculate size of a bubble
    var square = (value/1000 - minBulletSize) / (maxBulletSize - minBulletSize) * (maxSquare - minSquare) + minSquare;
    if (square < minSquare) {
        square = minSquare;
    }
    if (square > maxSquare) {
        square = maxSquare;
    }
    var size = Math.sqrt(square / (Math.PI * 2));
    var id = dataItem.code;
}
```

Comment: The title doesn't match with the description, update it

Comment: When visualizing the bubbles, instead of visualizing their actual values, visualize their logarithms

Comment: how many pixels can use? what is the size of the canvas? how many cities do you have? the circle size algorithm is dependent on the positioning algorithm you have at the moment so it would be great if you can share that also.

Comment: @svs I've added in my code above

Comment: @JohnDoe wait where are your circles? I was expecting `(x, y)` centers. I don't see what is the meaning of `min/maxBulletSize`, `min/maxSquare`, Could you explain your current idea. Semanticize your code.

Comment: @svs Where they're placed on the map isn't terribly important, I'm concerned with calculating the size. If you must know, they're being placed via lat/lon coordinates...

Comment: @JohnDoe so you are drawing on a map and I thought you are drawing on a canvas trying to do something like [this](http://www.wordle.net/) but with bubbles. what are `min/maxBulletSize`, `min/maxSquare` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a look at how to make a logarithmic function to look "logarithmic" within the constraints of 0.5 and 1 :

`Math.log10(x / 0.8 + 1) / 3 + 0.5` where x is in between 0 to 24.5.

This is purely a function that seems to look good for me where you can get very dynamic numbers early although a clear growth can be seen in larger numbers.

Feel free to mess around with the numbers, this is VERY subjective.

Next you will need to fit in your 100~15000 range within 0 to 24.5.
I would simply do a `x = (x - 100) / 608.16` to get your range to be within 0 to 24.5.

```
var minBulletSize = 7.5;
var maxBulletSize = 20;
var maxSquare = maxBulletSize * maxBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;
var minSquare = minBulletSize * minBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;

// create circle for each location
for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
    var dataItem = mapData[i];
    var value = dataItem.value;
    // assuming value is in between 100 and 15000
    value = (value - 100) / 608.16;
    value = Math.log10(value / 0.8 + 1) / 3.0 + 0.5;
    // value will be in between 0.5 and 1 on a logarithmic scale.
    // Do what you want with it :)
}
```

Tinker the values within the functions until you find a perfect curve for you.